# How to add IAM policy binding to a service account using Google Cloud Deployment Manager?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-deployment-manager

I want to write a [GCP Deployment Manager resource template](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/create-basic-template) that can create a IAM policy binding to a service account as a resource. In particular, I want to configure [allowing a member to impersonate a single service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts#impersonate-sa-level) with Deployment Manager.

I know this can be done with GCP console, [gcloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/add-iam-policy-binding) or [Pulumi](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/gcp/serviceaccount/iambinding/).

Maybe I'm missing something, but how can I achieve this with Deployment Manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Deployment Manager to create a IAM policy binding to a Service Account at the Service Account creation.

I test it in my own project using the following jinja file.

1. I created a deploy.jinja

```
resources:
- name: test-name-deploy
  type: iam.v1.serviceAccount
  properties:
    accountId: testing
    displayName: testing-sa
  accessControl:
    gcpIamPolicy:
      bindings:
      - role: roles/editor
        members:
        - "user:myuser@gmail.com"
```

2. I created a deployment:

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create mytestdm --template=deploy.jinja
```

And I received the following result:

```
NAME              TYPE                   STATE      ERRORS  INTENT
test-name-deploy  iam.v1.serviceAccount  COMPLETED  []
```

Take in consideration that you need the API iam.googleapis.com enable.

You can check the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/set-access-control-resources#setting_an_iam_policy_in_your_configuration) for further information.

Comment: That worked, thank you for the answer!
I didn't understand the `accessControl.gcpIamPolicy` section was for this purpose. Now it's clear!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I assumed I had to use `gcp-types/cloudresourcemanager-v1:virtual.projects.iamMemberBinding` for this but was wrong. Your example worked perfectly for creating an IAM policy binding for GKE Workload Identity.